# UICollectionViewController or CollectionView inside UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

Should I create collection view inside a ViewController or use UICollectionViewController. Are there any differences between them or am I overthinking?

Comment: Yes, your probably overthinking it.  The answer, generally, depends.  If you want to display "other" content on the view, then starting with a `UIViewController` might be a better solution (it's a lot easier to manage).  If all you want is the functionality of the `UICollectionView` itself, then a `UICollectionViewController` is a easier place to start

Answer (score 2):

UICollectionViewController inherits from UIViewController. If you want full control I recommend you to use your own UIViewController and add a UICollectionView as a subview, so you can place it wherever you want and resize it.